# Change the name of a class object Java, use class as array

Tags: java, class

**Here are my instructions:**
**Class Person**
has instance data members (all private) String fullName, char gender, int age.
has a public static int variable named numFriends with an initial value of zero.
has a constructor that will be used to make a Person object and assign values to its data members, and increment numFriends.
has getters and setters for all three instance data members.
has a `toString()` method that returns a string displaying the state of a Person instance.

**Class TestPerson**
This class needs a main method and two more methods. In main, create three Person instances and display their status. Then call the void changeName method (see below) to change the name of one of the Person objects. **Next, create an array of Person objects that holds the three instances created earlier. Then, call the agePersons method with this array and an integer as arguments.** The agePersons method is described below. It returns an array with all Person objects aged by the value of the yrs argument. Use a loop to process and display the status of the elements in the array returned by agePersons. Finally, display the value of the static numFriends attribute.

```
public static void changeName(Person p) {
}
```

this method should be used to change the name of the Person passed to it as an argument. See sample output.

```
public static Person[ ] agePersons(Person[ ] ara, int yrs) {
}
```

this method takes a Person array and an integer (for years) as arguments, and adds that many years to the age of every Person in the array. The modified array is then returned.

**SAMPLE OUTPUT**

```
Three people at first
Person fullName=Otto Mattik, gender=M, age=22
Person fullName=Anna Bollick, gender=F, age=19
Person fullName=Dick Tator, gender=M, age=33

Three persons after 5 years
Person fullName=Otto Mattik, gender=M, age=27
Person fullName=Anna Bollick-Mattik, gender=F, age=24
Person fullName=Dick Tator, gender=M, age=38

We created 3 Person objects.
```

So far here is my code:

```
class Person {

    private String fullName;
    private char gender; 
    private int age;

    public static int numFriends = 0;

    public void setName(String nm) {
        fullName = nm;
    }

    public void setAge(int a) {
        age = a;
    }

    public void setGender(char g) {
        gender = g;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return (fullName + " gender is " + gender + " age is " + age );
    }

}
```

And here is the second code file:

```
public class PersonTest {

    public static void changeName(Person p, String nm) {
    p.setName(nm);
}

    public static Person[ ] agePersons(Person[ ] ara, int yrs) {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Three People At First:");
        Person p1 = new Person(); // create Person
        p1.setAge(22);
        p1.setName("Otto Mattik");
        p1.setGender('M');

        Person p2 = new Person(); // create Person
        p2.setAge(19);
        p2.setName("Anna Bollick");
        p2.setGender('F');

        Person p3 = new Person(); // create Person
        p3.setAge(38);
        p3.setName("Dick Tator");
        p3.setGender('M');

        changeName(p2, "Anna Bollik-Mattik");
        System.out.println(p1.toString());
        System.out.println(p2.toString());
        System.out.println(p3.toString());
    }
}
```

And this is my output:

```
Three People At First:
Otto Mattik gender is M age is 22
Anna Bollick-Mattik gender is F age is 19
Dick Tator gender is M age is 38
```

**I'm having a tough time figuring out how to set up my array with the objects that were already created and getting the age to increase across the board.**

Comment: Where is the changeName() method being kept ? It seems flawed.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to iterate through all the `Person`s in the array

```
public static Person[ ] agePersons(Person[ ] ara, int yrs) {
    Person[] newArray = new Person[ara.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < ara.length; i++){
        newArray[i] = ara[i];
        newArray[i].setAge(newArray[i].getAge() + yrs);
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

Comment: You are copying references to `Person` objects. They still point to the same objects as in the original array and when you modify them, it doesn’t matter which reference you use, both arrays will reflect the change. It’s not different to `for(Person p: ara) p.setAge(p.getAge()+yrs); return ara.clone();` Though, it’s not clear why a new array has to be created at all, when the contents is the same.